# Rerouting network traffic to vpn

Tags: linux, networking, router, vpn, routing

I have an ubuntu server as router. Now I would like to route all traffic from subnet 1 (192.168.1.0) through a vpn connection. This works only when i let the vpn server push the routes to my router but now subnet2 (192.168.2.0) and the traffic coming from the router itself are also tunneled through the vpn.

Can anyone tell me how to set the routes so that only the traffic from subnet1 goes into the vpn connection and the traffic from subnet2 and from the server itself goes directly to the internet?

Routing table without vpn:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         31.19.38.254    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
31.19.38.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     0      0        0 p1p1
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     0      0        0 p1p2
```

with vpn push-gateway enabled

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.9.0.41       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
0.0.0.0         31.19.38.254    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.9.0.1        10.9.0.41       255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 tun0
10.9.0.41       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
31.19.38.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
128.0.0.0       10.9.0.41       128.0.0.0       UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     0      0        0 p1p1
192.168.2.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     0      0        0 p1p2
209.95.51.97    31.19.38.254    255.255.255.255 UGH   0      0        0 eth0
```

Interfaces:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr d0:50:99:26:c9:62  
          inet addr:31.19.38.94  Bcast:31.19.38.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::d250:99ff:fe26:c962/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1

p1p1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:94:4c:16  
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:17ff:fe94:4c16/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

p1p2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:15:17:94:4c:17  
          inet addr:192.168.2.1  Bcast:192.168.2.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
          inet6 addr: fe80::215:17ff:fe94:4c17/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

tun0      Link encap:UNSPEC  HWaddr 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  
          inet addr:10.9.0.54  P-t-P:10.9.0.53  Mask:255.255.255.255
          UP POINTOPOINT RUNNING NOARP MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
```

Comment: Which subnet is connected to the internet?

Comment: at the moment 192.168.0.0/16 is forwarded to eth0.

Comment: So the VPN is on your intranet or the Internet?

Comment: Start here.  http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html then search around, basically you need two routing tables, one redirected and one not, and you need rules to force nets to use one or the other.

Comment: Thank you, that site helped a lot. So in my case I would let the standard routing table as it is and only delete the rule for subnet1 and add this one to the new table? Where do I have to add the rule that the vpn traffic goes through eth0 ? Sorry for asking so many questions. Never had to work with routing tables before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zoredache has put you on the right track. The details of the answer are as follows:

1. Leave the VPN as is, this will setup the default routing table called `main`;
2. Now we setup a second routing table, for the packets that must **not** pass thru the VPN. We call the new routing table `novpn` (not a major flight of fancy there, I agree):

   ```
   echo 200 novpn >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
   ip route add 31.19.38.0/24 dev eth0 src YourIP table novpn
   ip route add default via 31.19.38.254 table novpn
   ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev p1p1 table novpn
   ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 dev p1p2 table novpn
   ```

   In the above, `YourIP` is the IP address of your `eth0` interface.
3. Now we set rules to distinguish what goes thru the VPN, and what does not:

   ```
   ip rule add from 192.168.1.0/24 table main
   ip rule add from 192.168.2.0/24 table novpn
   ```

   Remember to use the key rule,

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
   ```

   and to allow ipv4 forwarding, and you are done.

Comment: That finally worked . Thank you. I just have a litte problem with the traffic from the server. Sub1 uses the vpn and subnet 2 doen't as it should but the traffic from the server also uses the vpn connection.  I tried adding ip rule add from 127.0.0.1/1 table novpn but then subnet1 doesn't use the vpn.

Comment: That's the wrong rule, pls delete it. You should use instead `ip rule add from YourIP table novpn`. where, once again, `YourIP` is the IP address of the `eth0` interface.

Comment: I added the rule but nothing changed.

Comment: @Stefan You should add a higher priority (=lower number!!!) for this new rule than for the rule for the whole network, 192.168.1.0/24. Pls read here http://superuser.com/questions/359923/significance-of-priority-in-ip-rule-command